# Embedding word document in to PowerBI

Tags: dictionary, ms-word, powerbi, tooltip, visualization

I want to insert a word document into Power BI and show it on the tooltip.

Example:
There is a map visualization showing total sales based on the product. If I select a region on the map the tooltip has to show a word document with all the data about that product. Is there any anyway to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the Word document to HTML and use custom visuals like [Shielded HTML Viewer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa200002144?tab=overview), [HTML Content](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa200001930?tab=overview), or similar to add the document to your report, or convert the document to an image and avoid the usage of custom visuals
whatsoever.

Whatever you use, to make it a tooltip, place it on a separate report page that will serves as your tooltip. Change its `Page size` to be `Tooltip`. In `Page information` flip the `Tooltip` switch to `On` and into the `Tooltip fields` add the field with your product.

For more information and step-by-step instructions how to do that, see [Create tooltips based on report pages in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-tooltips).